# VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing not returning complete image WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control, screenshot

i am trying to create image from `webBrowser` control's output. the following is what i have tried. and somewhat achieved what i want, but problem is the image is not of full height, it gets trims after some height.

In the picture you can see there are 4 rows but the image is 2 n half rows. please guide.

HTML 1-4 is in `webBrowser`, and after space 1-3 is image created from code below.

[image]

here is code:

```
    private void WebBrowser1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = (WebBrowser)sender;
        var htmlDoc = wb.Document as mshtml.HTMLDocument;
        if (htmlDoc == null || htmlDoc.body == null) return;
        var body = (mshtml.IHTMLElement2)htmlDoc.body;
        wb.Height = body.scrollHeight;
        wb.Width = body.scrollWidth;

        var imgScreen = new Image
        {
            Width = body.scrollWidth,
            Height = body.scrollHeight,
            Source = new DrawingImage(VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing(wb))
        };

        // Add Image to the UI
        StackPanel1.Children.Add(imgScreen);
    }
```

Also tried the following code same result:

```
        DrawingVisual vis = new DrawingVisual();
        DrawingContext cont = vis.RenderOpen();
        cont.DrawDrawing(VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing(wb));
        cont.Close();

        RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap(body.scrollWidth, body.scrollHeight, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
        rtb.Render(vis);
        imgScreen1.Source = rtb;
```

Comment: Why dont you try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891345/get-a-screenshot-of-a-specific-application ?

Answer (score 1):

The `WebBrowser` control is really just a wrapper around an ActiveX control, so will not render off-screen in the same way that a regular UIElement would.

[MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

*The WebBrowser control internally instantiates the native WebBrowser ActiveX control.*

Fortunately, it looks like there is a blog already working around the limitations of this control:

[Yishai Galatzer](http://blogs.iis.net/yigalatz/archive/2012/03/21/rendering-an-image-from-an-embedded-web-browser-c-wpf-application.aspx)

Comment: i already know what you have written, but its not related to my question.